# Adding and removing dynamically generated buttons in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, button, dynamic, gesture

This is a strange one.

I'm quite new to Xcode. I've been trying to make a simple app that adds new buttons when you single click on the button view and removes them when you double click.

Adding buttons is OK, but removing them is unreliable. I think it has something to do with the way I've written the code because it only seems to remove the most recently added button on double click and not the actual button I've clicked on.

My abridged .m Code is below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapper {

//adds the buttons and gives them a unique tag

ButtonCount  = ButtonCount+1;
btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150);
btn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
btn.tag=PuckCount;

//attaches double tap recognizer to button

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                      initWithTarget:self
                                                            action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
[doubleTapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[btn addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGestureRecognizer];



//Add Tap Recognizer to pucks to create new buttons

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                      initWithTarget:self
                                                      action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[singleTapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[singleTapGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapGestureRecognizer];
[btn addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"puck2.png"];
[btn setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
}


//handles what happens on a double tap - THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE PROBLEM IS.

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)doubletap{

PuckSelected = self.view.tag;
[[self.btn viewWithTag:PuckSelected] removeFromSuperview];
}
@end
```

Comment: You can't add and remove buttons in Xcode. You can, however, add or remove buttons in your iOS app. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove the button that is being double tapped, then try this.

```
- (void) handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *) doubletap {
   [doubletap.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

The UIGestureRecognizer has the view attached to it. There is no need to retrieve it again. Plus your problem was that you were trying to retrive the view from self instead of doubletap

Comment: Thanks. Thats's fixed it! Still getting the hang of what everything is referred to. Really helped!

Comment: If this fixed your problem then accept this as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)doubletap{
  PuckSelected = self.view.tag;
  [[self.btn viewWithTag:PuckSelected] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

According to the code above, the button that gets removed it the button that has the same tag as `self.view`. But you don't show how `self.view`s tag gets set, so it's impossible for us to know why or how your code selects the button that will be removed.

Regardless, you're probably heading down the wrong road here. It looks like you might have buttons nested inside a button? Which is odd. Also, you're using gesture recognizers with `UIButton`s, which don't need it. They already respond to things like taps and double-taps via the [target-action mechanism](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW14).

Generally speaking, controls (that is, objects that derive from `UIControl`) already handle touches, taps, and other simple interactions. You'd really only use gesture recognizers on `UIView`s that need to track swipes or pinches or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Your handleDoubleTap method doesn't make sense.
Do something like this ::

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)doubletap{

    PuckSelected = doubletap.view.tag;
    [[self.view viewWithTag:PuckSelected] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be 2 problems with your code. 
1. When you do a single tap you are adding a button at (0,0,150,150) so any new button that gets added will be on top of the previous button. Maybe I am seeing this because of your abridged code, but you may want to do something about that. 
2. In the UITapgesturerecognizer it will give you the view(id) that was tapped. You should use that in your selector. Like: 
 `doubletap.view.tag`.